# Is it possible to access some "format code settings".

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible for the languages we can use the format, to configure our proper format settings? Like use only tabs, setting up when to endl, when to space etc.

Comment: I'm also wondering this. Would like to use VSC professionally but the company I'm working for are using formatting settings not yet available. Such as 'space between non-empty parentesis', etc.